# starting Activities from an expandable list dynamically

Tags: java, android, iphone

I am attempting to start an activity from the children of my expandable list This framework is taken from the sample in the Android SDK, and is the core for my application.  Here is teh code and I will identify which areas are not working.

```
package com.soraingraven.suprRef;

import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SuperReferenceActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {
    ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set up our adapter
        mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        //registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());
        getExpandableListView().setOnChildClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(parent, v, groupPosition, childPosition, id);
        String testName[][] = children[groupPosition][childPosition];
        try {
            Class clazz = Class.forName("com.soraingraven.suprRef." + testName);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, clazz);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        // use groupPosition and childPosition to locate the current item in the adapter
        return true;
    }

    /*@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Sample menu");
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Sample action");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        String title = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();

        int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
        if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
            int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition); 
            int childPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition); 
            Toast.makeText(this, title + ": Child " + childPos + " clicked in group " + groupPos,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        } else if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
            int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition); 
            Toast.makeText(this, title + ": Group " + groupPos + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }*/ //Context Menu Stuff May or may not use

    //Indexes for all the options
    public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
        private String[] groups = {"Math Formulas and Equations"};                                  //Main Menu

        private String[][] children = {                                                             //Sub Menus
                { "PerfectGasLaw" }                                                             //Math Equations Sub Menu         
        };

        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
        }

        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return children[groupPosition].length;
        }

        public TextView getGenericView() {
            AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 128);
            TextView textView = new TextView(SuperReferenceActivity.this);
            textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
            textView.setPadding(128, 0, 0, 0);
            return textView;
        }

        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = getGenericView();
            textView.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
            return textView;
        }

        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groups[groupPosition];
        }

        public int getGroupCount() {
            return groups.length;
        }

        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = getGenericView();
            textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
            return textView;
        }

        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Line 31 I cannot figure out how to get the super reference class to accept the children array, as it is listed as private to another class.  Please help.  Im not sure if i need to create a 2D array inside the activity class and pass it the data contained in children or what exactly needs to be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to concatenate a 2d String array to a String! Remove the [][]

```
    String testName = children[groupPosition][childPosition];
    try {
        Class clazz = Class.forName("com.soraingraven.suprRef." + testName);
```

Comment: I made type testname a 2D string array, but children is out of scope for this function.  What would be the best way to get it into the correct scope without breaking the existing list.

Comment: Easiest way is to make it a private class in your activity where it has scope.

Comment: It seems onchild click is a function which android calls autmatically under the listener.  So you cannot add parameters which is what you would need to do to pass children as a string array into the function.  So im using switch cases and the group and child position data to determine what was selected, not as dynamic as id like, but a solution is a solution.